# How to get values of jTextField real time?

Tags: java, swing, actionlistener, jtextfield, documentlistener

I am having trouble with setting up actionlistener to jtextfield. I want to update string based on users input in jtextfield in real time. As of now I have added actionlistener to jtextfield that allows me to update my after I press enter in jtextfield.

I was just wondering is there anyway that I can do it in real time ?

Thanks too suggestions from Hovercraft Full Of Eels, I dot this thing working.
Following is the code that I used if somebody stumble upon this questions again

```
jtextfieldName.getDocument().addDocumentListener(new DocumentListener() {

        @Override
        public void removeUpdate(DocumentEvent arg0) {
            // TODO put what you would like to do when text is deleted

        }

        @Override
        public void insertUpdate(DocumentEvent arg0) {
            // TODO put what you would like to do when text is added
        }

        @Override
        public void changedUpdate(DocumentEvent arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }
    });
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One possibility is to add a DocumentListener to the JTextField's PlainDocument. If you want to filter the information such that you want to prevent some type of text from being entered, then consider using a DocumentFilter instead.

Answer (score 3):

You want to use either a [`DocumentListener`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/event/DocumentListener.html) or, if you want to change/filter what the user is entering, a [`DocumentFilter`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/text/DocumentFilter.html)

There are dozens of examples on SO, but you can have a look at [MDP's Weblog](http://www.jroller.com/dpmihai/entry/documentfilter) for some other examples as well